# How to return a list from a class

Tags: python, class

How would I get to return a list from the class, right now its just returning the location

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=[]):
        self.val = val

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.val)


def file_reader(file_path):
    list_of_num = [] 
    with open(file_path, "rt") as fout:
        reader = csv.reader(fout, delimiter=",")
        for line in reader:
            list_of_num.append(line)
    return list_of_num

def list_instances():
    lists = file_reader(list_path)
    final_list = ListNode(lists)
    return final_list 


if __name__=="__main__":
    file_reader(list_path)
    print(list_instances())
```

Any ideas, I think it has something to do with the iter object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `ListNode` class, which doesn't do anything other than wrap a regular `list` (it also has a potential bug related to the mutable default arg in the constructor that might bite you later), and it doesn't wrap the `__str__` method that provides pretty-printing.

The easiest way to solve the problem is to just not use `ListNode`:

```
def list_instances():
    return file_reader(list_path)
```

Now your `print` call will receive a `list` instead of a `ListNode` and it will print the contents of the list.

You can also write `file_reader()` more simply as:

```
def file_reader(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "rt") as fout:
        return list(csv.reader(fout))
```

since `csv.reader` is an iterable, and passing an iterable to `list()` will give you a `list` of its contents; you don't need to write the `for` loop yourself and individually `append` each element.